# How do I allign the Text in one column of a Gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, text, alignment

My program displays on a application a gridview with numbers in the left column and names in the right column. I want the numbers in the left column to align to the right instead of how they are currently aligned to the left. I've tried several solutions online but none seem to be working.
Ex.
Current:

```
500000   |nameofstuff
3203     |stuffstuff
33       |lalalalala
```

desired:

```
 500000|nameofstuff                        
   3203|stuffstuff    
     33|lalalalala
```

Current GridView setup. I might be doing something wrong.

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

xml, there is really nothing here at the moment since all the attempts I've tried haven't worked

```
  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|right"
    android:numColumns="2" >
  </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a custom adapter and override getView() method to set the gravity of the textview based on the position.

You might refer following link for custom adapter-http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/